# HTML have A element react to bootstrap breakpoints

Tags: bootstrap-4, breakpoints

The below boostrap code works exactly like I want it to on different screens!

Basically, when it is a large screen, I want the 3 items on one line and when it is a smaller screen I want each item on it's own line and where each item goes from end to end.

(yay!) However, When I replace the alert class with an `a href` tag, the functionality breaks (see below). What's the best way to make the buttons perform like I want?

Works

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4'>
        <div class='alert btn-primary' >primary alert</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4'>
        <div class='alert btn-primary'>primary alert</div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4'>
        <div class='alert btn-primary' >primary alert</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doesn't work

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4'>
        <a href="/" class="alert btn-primary">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4'>
        <a href="/" class="alert btn-primary">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4'>
        <a href="/" class="alert btn-primary">Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to know how you want to **structure** your elements : I don't really know what you are doing it for but I guess the following :

- You want a grid structure (`class="row"` & `class="col-*"`)
- You need to link some *elements* (`<a></a>`)
- Those *element* are buttons (`<button></button>`)
- You want those button to take the entire width of the parent container (`class="w-100"`)

After computing those constraints, we end up with the following code, which is pretty similar to what you initially wrote (yay!):

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4'>
        <a href="/">
          <button class="alert btn-primary w-100">Home</button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4'>
        <a href="/">
          <button class="alert btn-primary w-100">Home</button>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-12 col-lg-4'>
        <a href="/">
          <button class="alert btn-primary w-100">Home</button>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```